# How to get the currently engine that is used for agora react native?

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I am wondering how i can get the current engine that is used for the agora version v4. Realized there could be duplicates within the agora engine within the same device when i run createAgoraRtcEngine. How do i detect the current engines thats running on the device and how do i destory all current engine thats running on the device

```
import {AudioProfileType, AudioScenarioType, ChannelProfileType, ClientRoleType, createAgoraRtcEngine} from 'react-native-agora';

export const getEngine = async() => {
//creates a new engine every time so agora detects 2 users are on this engine
    const engine = createAgoraRtcEngine();
    engine.initialize({appId: process.env.AGORA_APP_ID});
    return engine;
}
```